# Get parent node of the node in a rose tree

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get the parent node of the node in a rose tree using following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}
                   deriving (Show, Generic, Functor)

type Timestamp = Integer

type Tree = RoseTree Timestamp 

getParentNode :: Timestamp -> Tree -> Maybe Timestamp 
getParentNode node tree@(RoseTree _ []) = Nothing
getParentNode node tree@(RoseTree rootNode (x:xs)) =
  if node == value x then Just rootNode else case getParentNode node x of 
    Nothing -> case getParentNodeForList node (children x) of 
      Nothing -> getParentNodeForList node xs
      Just parent -> Just parent
    Just parent -> Just parent 

getParentNodeForList :: Timestamp -> [Tree]-> Maybe Timestamp
getParentNodeForList node [] = Nothing
getParentNodeForList node (x:xs) = case getParentNode node x of 
  Nothing -> case getParentNodeForList node (children x) of 
    Nothing -> getParentNodeForList node xs
    Just parent -> Just parent
  Just parent -> Just parent 


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let tree = RoseTree 1623839394 [RoseTree 1623839395 [], RoseTree 1623839396 [], RoseTree 1623839397 []]
  putStrLn $ show $ getParentNode 1623839397 tree
```

The output is `Nothing` for this case. I do not understand why. I covered all possible cases of traversing in `getParentNode` and `getParentNodeForList` (at least it seems so, it doesn't work apparently).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what `getParentNode` and `getParentNodeList` are supposed to do? I think I can guess `getParentNode` from the name, but `getParentNodeList` is a bit ambiguous and I don't know why you would use it in the definition of the `getParentNode` function.

Comment: `getParentNodeList` searches for the occurence of `node` in rose tree children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `getParentNode` should recurse on `getParentNode node (RoseTree rootNode xs)`, so the whole function would become:

```hs
getParentNode :: Timestamp -> Tree -> Maybe Timestamp 
getParentNode node tree@(RoseTree _ []) = Nothing
getParentNode node tree@(RoseTree rootNode (x:xs)) =
  if node == value x then Just rootNode else case getParentNode node x of 
    Nothing -> case getParentNodeForList node (children x) of 
      Nothing -> getParentNode node (RoseTree rootNode xs)
      Just parent -> Just parent
    Just parent -> Just parent
```

Personally, I would make use of [`asum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) to write it more succinctly:

```hs
getParentNode node (RoseTree x xs)
  | node `elem` map value xs = pure x
  | otherwise = asum (map (getParentNode node) xs)
```

Comment: I hope this is a good answer, because I need to port it to F#. I have a RoseTree in F#, but it doesn't have a getParentNode function. I need to traverse all the ancestors (aka the path) of a node.